# Cannot grab text in class element on webpage - Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'd like to grab the text inside the class element named "company-name" in the following html:

```
<h3 class="company-name"><a class="link" data-send-tracking="true" href="/sales/accounts/insights?companyId=3025784">Opera Mediaworks</a></h3>
```

So in this case, what I'd like to grab is "Opera Mediaworks".

However, I keep getting the following error:

```
extensions::uncaught_exception_handler:8 Error in response to tabs.query: TypeError: Cannot read property 'textContent' of null
    at Object.callback (chrome-extension://ecphajfcjjcikhaiohndnkfcjhfganef/grabcomanddefinecompet.js:12:68)
    at HTMLButtonElement.abc (chrome-extension://ecphajfcjjcikhaiohndnkfcjhfganef/grabcomanddefinecompet.js:8:14)
```

My code for this function are as follow:

```
function grabcom() {

    var companyname = document.getElementsByClassName("company-name").innerHTML;
    console.log(companyname);

}

grabcom();
```

I have tried all the following but still couldn't work:

```
    var companyname = document.getElementsByClassName("company-name")[0].innerHTML
    var companyname = document.getElementsByClassName("company-name")[0]
    var companyname = document.getElementsByClassName("company-name")[0].textContent
```

What is missing??

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to grab the inner HTML of the `<a>` tag, since you only want 'Opera MediaWorks' rather than everything inside the `<h3>` tag.

So this should get what you want:

`var companyName = document.getElementsByClassName('link')[0].innerHTML`

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks!